# Pass filename from Nautilus to shell script

Tags: linux, debian, nautilus

I am trying to execute a shell script that gets for an argument a file name.

I can do it if I go to the terminal and type the full PATH.

But I am trying to make this more user friendly so I what I want to do is to send the argument (complete path) from the file manager or nautilus.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: @kaylum I think there's an implied "how?".

Comment: @kaylum ... How can I do it?? like go to the file manager and start an script than gets for an argument the path of a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I am going to share a way I found that works.

All I was trying to do was to pass a path as an argument, without typing it on the command line. to make it user friendly.

So I use a zenity tool, file selection, to browse through the file manager and select the file.

```
./script.sh $(zenity --file-selection)
```

See, now I am passing the path of the file I selected.

If you want to try this out, just type in the command line.

```
zenity --file-selection
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. Here's a way to do it:

Copy your script to the folder `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/` -- please note that this path will expand to include the current user information, such as: `/home/john/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/`.

Now, on your script, capture the argument using `$1`. For example, let's say that your script is intended to delete the file, then your script could be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f "$1"
exit
```

Now, restart `Nautilus` and navigate to the file you want to execute the action on. Right-click the file, and on the menu that appears, choose "scripts", and on the sumenu that appears, choose your script name -- that will execute your script with the file name as argument.

Note: don't forget to make your script executable first, for example: `chmod +x /home/john/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/myScript`

Comment: Hey Thankyou thats an amazing answer with everything so clear.
I am going to try that right now.
I also found another way to do it.
It is not exactly executing an script from nautilus but it works for me.

I am sharing as someone might find this useful.

When executing your script, use zenity file selection tool.

In my example ./script.sh $(zenity --file-selection)

That will allow you to browse through your files and when you select a file. The path is passed as an argument to your script.

Again thanks everyone for the help and good luck everybody.

Comment: You're welcome. When an answer helped you on stack Overflow, consider upvoting that answer so that it will signal to others that it is a good answer. Another thing: if your script requires root privileges to work, you can still achieve that by using `gksudo` on the invocation.