# Output current Nautilus selection to shell

Tags: linux, bash, nautilus

I am trying to output the current selection in Nautilus to the shell, so I can pass the output to other scripts for processing.

Something that would allow me to do this:

```
sh nautilus_selection.sh | parallel sh some_other_command.sh
```

Basically, the opposite operation to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516147/pass-filename-from-nautilus-to-shell-script) - the reason being that I do not want the processing scripts (for example - but not limited to - image resizing) to be exclusive to Nautilus.

Is that possible?

Comment: Try looking up `xargs -I`. It is meant exactly for cases like this

Comment: @inian - parallel is similar to args, and I am familiar with both. MY problem is how to get the name of the selected file from nautilus